# Delphi 7 Invalid Pointer Operation with Custom Component

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, delphi-7

I have a custom component class that I use as a framework to load comments and user details, etc, onto a form. The Class is a sub-class of a panel and contains 3 labels and a memo.

Upon Closing my form, or trying to free the object, i get a "Invalid Pointer Operation" error. I know this is from trying to free an object twice, or accessing RAM that is not available. However, I don't know how to fix it. It's holding me back quite a bit, as I have to load different comments on different topics, and I cannot until I clear the form of the current comments.

Here is the class-related code:

```
    type
      TSkeleton = class(TPanel)
        private
        fName : TLabel;
        fStudNo : TLabel;
        fTimeAndDate : TLabel;
        fComment : TMemo;
     public
       Constructor Create (AOwner: TComponent); overload; override;
       constructor Create(AOwner:TForm; sName, sStudNo, sTime, sDate, sComment: string; ComCount: integer); overload;
 end;
{ TSkeleton }

constructor TSkeleton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
//
end;

constructor TSkeleton.Create(AOwner: TForm; sName, sStudNo, sTime, sDate,
  sComment: string; ComCount: integer);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Parent := AOwner;
  Width := 800;
  Height := 250;
  Top := 448+((ComCount-1)*250);
  Left := 16;
  BevelInner := bvSpace;
  BevelOuter := bvLowered;

  fName := TLabel.Create(fName);
  self.InsertControl(fName);
  with fName do
  begin
   Caption := sName;
   Font.Name := 'Garamond';
   Font.Size  := 30;
   Left := 7;
   Top := 4;
  end;

  fStudNo := TLabel.Create(fStudNo);
  self.InsertControl(fStudNo);
    with fStudNo do
      begin
       Caption := sStudNo;
       Font.Name := 'Garamond';
       Font.Size  := 15;
       Left := 15;
       Top := 52;
      end;

  fTimeAndDate := TLabel.Create(fTimeAndDate);
  self.InsertControl(fTimeAndDate);
    with fTimeAndDate do
      begin
       Caption := sTime + ' ' + sDate;
       Font.Name := 'Garamond';
       Font.Size  := 20;
       Left := 583;
       Top := 4;
      end;

  fComment := TMemo.Create(fComment);
  self.InsertControl(fComment);
    with fComment do
      begin
       Lines.Add(sComment);
       Font.Name := 'Garamond';
       Font.Size  := 12;
       Left := 152;
       Top := 56;
       Height := 161;
       Width := 633;
       ReadOnly := True;
       ScrollBars := ssVertical;
      end;

end;
```

If you would like to see the other code used (reading the textfile, creating the array of objects, etc) please say so. It's not directly related to the class so I did not think it would be necessary.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Based on @Remy Lebeau's code, and @NGLN's comments, I have decided to post everything necessary.

After fixing the class based on @Remy's code, I was still receiving the error. This led me to believe the error was where I was using the class, particularly in the array of objects I was creating.

Previously, my code was

```
  for i := 0 to ComCount-1 do
  begin
    fArrObjects[i+1] :=  TSkeleton.Create(TargetForm);
    with fArrObjects[i+1] do
    begin
      Parent := TargetForm;
      TheName := fArrComments[i][0];
      StudNo := fArrComments[i][1];
      Time := fArrComments[i][2];
      Date := fArrComments[i][3];
      Comment := fArrComments[i][4];
      ComCount := i+1;
    end;
```

Changing

```
fArrObjects[i+1]
```

to

```
 fArrObjects[i]
```

solved the issue.

Thank you to @Remy for correcting the errors in the class.

Comment: As an update on this: @Remy's suggestion below works in a seperate application. However, in my main application, I am still getting the error. Which leads me to think it is as a result of the dynamic array not being Free'd.

Comment: A dynamic array can't be freed and doesn't require manual destruction. But this "dynamic array" is now falling from the sky into this topic. And there's certainly more up there, because with the current information, we cannot help you. Please provide more. Try to extend the test application until it errors, or strip the actual application until it doesn't. Then you know.

Comment: I did not think the array relevant at the time, I thought the error was with the Component itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems with your code.

```
Parent := AOwner;
```

Do not set the `Parent` from inside of the constructor.  It is the responsibility of the caller to set the `Parent` after the object is fully constructed first.

You do not have a destructor defined, and you are creating your child objects with `nil` Owners. `TSkeleton` should be the Owner instead, eg:

```
//fName := TLabel.Create(fName);
fName := TLabel.Create(Self);
...
```

You should not be calling `InsertControl()` directly.  Use the `Parent` property instead, eg:

```
//self.InsertControl(fName);
fName.Parent := Self;
...
```

Why do you have two constructors? Your overridden constructor does not do anything, not even call the base constructor, and your custom constructor is not called at design-time (unless you have other code that is creating instances of `TSkeleton` programmably).  I suggest you get rid of the custom constructor and expose published properties to manipulate the child controls as needed.

Lastly, since you are creating sub-components, you should mark them as such via `TComponent.SetSubComponen()`.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
type
  TSkeleton = class(TPanel)
  private
    fName : TLabel;
    fStudNo : TLabel;
    fTimeAndDate : TLabel;
    fComment : TMemo;

    fTime: string;
    fDate: string;
    fComCount: Integer;

    function GetTheName: string;
    procedure SetTheName(const AValue: string);
    function GetStudNo: string;
    procedure SetStudNo(const AValue: string);
    procedure SetTime(const AValue: string);
    procedure SetDate(const AValue: string);
    function GetComment: string;
    procedure SetComment(const AValue: string);
    procedure SetComCount(AValue: integer);

  public
    constructor Create (AOwner: TComponent); override;

  published
    property TheName: string read GetTheName write SetTheName;
    property StudNo: string read GetStudNo write SetStudNo;
    property Time: string read fTime write SetTime;
    property Date: string read fDate write SetDate;
    property Comment: string read GetComment write SetComment;
    property ComCount: integer read fComCount write SetComCount;
  end;
```

```
constructor TSkeleton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  Width := 800;
  Height := 250;
  Left := 16;
  BevelInner := bvSpace;
  BevelOuter := bvLowered;

  fName := TLabel.Create(Self);
  fName.SetSubComponent(True);
  fName.Parent := Self;
  fName.Font.Name := 'Garamond';
  fName.Font.Size  := 30;
  fName.Left := 7;
  fName.Top := 4;

  fStudNo := TLabel.Create(Self);
  fStudNo.SetSubComponent(True);
  fStudNo.Parent := Self;
  fStudNo.Font.Name := 'Garamond';
  fStudNo.Font.Size  := 15;
  fStudNo.Left := 15;
  fStudNo.Top := 52;

  fTimeAndDate := TLabel.Create(Self);
  fTimeAndDate.SetSubComponent(True);
  fTimeAndDate.Parent := Self;
  fTimeAndDate.Font.Name := 'Garamond';
  fTimeAndDate.Font.Size  := 20;
  fTimeAndDate.Left := 583;
  fTimeAndDate.Top := 4;

  fComment := TMemo.Create(Self);
  fComment.SetSubComponent(True);
  fComment.Parent := Self;
  fComment.Font.Name := 'Garamond';
  fComment.Font.Size  := 12;
  fComment.Left := 152;
  fComment.Top := 56;
  fComment.Height := 161;
  fComment.Width := 633;
  fComment.ReadOnly := True;
  fComment.ScrollBars := ssVertical;
end;

function TSkeleton.GetTheName: string;
begin
  Result := fName.Caption;
end;

procedure TSkeleton.SetTheName(const AValue: string);
begin
  fName.Caption := AValue;
end;

function TSkeleton.GetStudNo: string;
begin
  Result := fStudNo.Caption;
end;

procedure TSkeleton.SetStudNo(const AValue: string);
begin
  fStudNo.Caption := AValue;
end;

procedure TSkeleton.SetTime(const AValue: string);
begin
  if fTime <> AValue then
  begin
    fTime := AValue;
    fTimeAndDate.Caption := fTime + ' ' + fDate;
  end;
end;

procedure TSkeleton.SetDate(const AValue: string);
begin
  if fDate <> AValue then
  begin
    fDate := AValue;
    fTimeAndDate.Caption := fTime + ' ' + fDate;
  end;
end;

function TSkeleton.GetComment: string;
begin
  Result := fComment.Text;
end;

procedure TSkeleton.SetComment(const AValue: string);
begin
  fComment.Text := AValue;
end;

procedure TSkeleton.SetComCount(AValue: integer);
begin
  if fComCount <> AValue then
  begin
    fComCount := AValue;
    Top := 448+((FComCount-1)*250);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick advice. I have adjusted my code accordingly. I have written the following destructor (it must be incorrect, I am still receiving the error) :

`destructor TSkeleton.Destroy;  
begin  
  fName.Free;  
  fStudNo.Free;  
  fTimeAndDate.Free;  
  fComment.Free;  
  inherited;  
end;`  

I am not sure if I am creating the object correctly, but the Top Property of the object does not change according to  the ComCount variable.

Comment: Remy pointed you at your missing destructor because your controls weren't owned. In this renewed setup, a destructor isn't needed because all sub-components are owned by the component.

Comment: Thank you @NGLN. I am a high school student and the most difficult OOP we do is, well, it's not. As I said above, I think the error I am getting may be due to the arrays not being finalized, which I am working on a solution to now.